# Why is program not accurately computing integer SUM?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm new to Assembly Programming (x86), and cannot figure out where I am going wrong in my program. After I redisplay the value that was moved into the array, I then want to display the current 'SUM'. I thought that by using the 'ebx' register, since it is used nowhere else in the program except in Loop2, that the value would not be overwritten and thus each 'add' statement would add the new array position value to my 'SUM'.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

[image: ConsoleWindow]

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
COUNT = 3

.data
inputMsg BYTE "Input an integer: ", 0
outputMsg BYTE "Redisplaying the integers: ", 0dh, 0ah, 0
sumMsg BYTE " Sum is now: ", 0
strArray SDWORD COUNT DUP(?)

.code
main PROC
    ; Read Integers from User
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, COUNT
    mov edx, OFFSET inputMsg
    mov esi, OFFSET strArray

L1: call WriteString            ; Display Prompt
    call ReadInt                ; Read input from user
    mov [esi], eax              ; Store value into array
    add esi, TYPE strArray      ; Move to next array position
    loop L1

    call Crlf

    ; Redisplay the integers
    mov edx, OFFSET outputMsg   ; Display 'outputMsg'
    call WriteString
    mov ecx, COUNT
    mov esi, OFFSET strArray

L2: mov ebx, 0                  ; Initialize ebx to 0
    mov eax, [esi]              ; Get integer from array
    call WriteInt               ; Display integer
    mov edx, OFFSET sumMsg      ; Display value of 'sumMsg'
    call WriteString
    ; mov eax, ebx
    add ebx, [esi]

    mov eax, ebx   ; <---- MOVED from above add ebx, [esi]

    call WriteInt
    call Crlf                   
    add esi, TYPE strArray      ; Move to next array position
    loop L2

    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move ebx to eax before you call WriteInt. Initializing ebx to 0 before the summation loop would be a good idea too.

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested (if I understood correctly). Now all lines read as the output form the array, followed by `"Sum is now: +0"`. I've edited my code above to reflect the changes. Any more ideas?

Comment: You've put `mov eax, ebx` in the wrong place. Put it just before `call WriteInt`

Comment: I moved `mov eax, ebx` under `add ebx, [esi]` and above `call WriteInt`. now output is: 
`+1 Sum is now: +1
+2 Sum is now: +2 
+3 Sum is now: +3`
What am I still missing?

Comment: `mov ebx, 0` should be before `L2`, otherwise you're resetting your sum to 0 every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have to "mov eax, ebx" before calling the last WriteInt.

Comment: I've edited my code as you and ooga suggested. Output now reads as the array value followed by `"Sum is now: +0"` with my modified code. Any further ideas?